# Change Background color with Switch case

Tags: javascript, react-native

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import AwesomeButton from 'react-native-really-awesome-button';

let randomHex = () => {
  let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  console.log(color);
  return color;
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };

    this.states = {
      backgroundColor: randomHex(),
    };
  }

  onPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    });
  };

  renkDegis = (count, color) => {
    switch (count) {
      case 10:
        color = 'black';
        break;

      case 20:
        b = this.randomHex();
        break;

      default:
        null;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: this.renkDegis(this.state.count),
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.textDesign}>{this.state.count}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.btnStyle}
          onPress={this.onPress}></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: randomHex(),
    alignItems: 'center',
    //  justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I wanna change the color when the count is 10 and 20 and 30. but Where is my wrong?
can you compile my code? when I press the button ten times, it gives me a warning.

ı created randomHex() and ı use this. But it gives me a warning.

Comment: `this.states`...?

Answer (score 1):

You should return value from `renkDegis` function,

Sample

```js
renkDegis = (count) => {
  let choosen;

  switch (count) {
    case 10:
      choosen = 'black';
      break;
    case 20:
      choosen = randomHex();
      break;
    default:
      null;
  }

  return choosen;
};
```

Hope this will help!